# basic аутентификация для одной папки

Tags: php, apache

Друзья здравствуйте! Вижу что данная тема еще не освещалась на рус. версии данного ресурса в таком формате, по этому прошу подключиться к решению вопроса. Необходимо методом basic аут. защитить дерикторию на сервере, либо, если это возможно, конкретный файл. Как я понимаю все сводится к тому, что нужно прописать некоторые настройки в .htaccess. Кто может помочь готовым решением (кодом).

Мною была сгенерированна пара логин пароль, которую я вставил в файл. В .httaccess, который лежит в корне файла я прописал следующий код:

```
AuthName "Login"
AuthUserFile /home/admin/web/mydomain.com/public_html/terminals/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /home/admin/web/mydomain.com/public_html/terminals
AuthType Basic
<LIMIT GET POST>
require valid-user
</LIMIT>
```

Но в результате я получаю запрос авторизации на всех страницах сайта, а не в конкретной дериктории. Пожалуйста помогите отредактировать код

Comment: Возможно, вы сможете помочь отредактировать мой код, что бы получился желаемый результат?

Comment: Ну так положи этот файл  .httaccess в ту директорию, которую надо закрыть

Comment: как вариант вы правы, я думал просто можно прописать какие то настройки для файла который  корне лежит на конкретную дерикторию

Comment: можно и в центральном, но сама суть файла .htaccess в том что это per-directory configuration file. то есть наиболее логичным будет просто положить в каталог. Но если хочется управлять из главного, то можно использовать директиву <Directory>. Для конкретного файла можно указать <files>